# How To Solve 504 Bad Gateway Timeout Error From Aws Api Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, http-status-code-504, aws-vpc-peering

## I am getting 504 Bad Gateway Timeout error in responce but data gets inserted sucessfully to the databse.

[image: Error Message]

---

**Code executes perfectly locally with response time within 1.15s but whenever deployed to lambda it start giving this Timeout Error.**

`Node js Endpoint Route is as Follows`

```
route.post("/Register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new userschema({
      Name: req.body.Name,
      Email: req.body.Email,
      UserName: req.body.UserName,
      PhotoUrl: req.body.PhotoUrl,
    });
    await user.save();
    return res.status.send("Created");
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send("Something Went Wrong");
  }
});
```

**I have Deployed Nodejs backend to aws lambda which is running in a VPC and using mongodb atlas it follow this architecture**

[image]

> I am new to aws so i followed [This Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/kWhIwlNkZm4/).

`Data gets inserted to mongodb atlas Database sucessfully. So the Vpc Peering conncetion beetween lambda function and Mongodb Atlas must be all right`.

Cloudwatch Logs is as Follows

[image: Logs]

[image: Logs]

[image: Logs]

I tried everything i could but still facing this issue.

Comment: your lambda is in VPC and making a call to sts. Please make sure you have VPCEndpoint configured for STS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_sts_vpce.html

Comment: I was missing this, now i have configured vpce to service - com.amazonaws.ap-south-1.sts allowed all resources connected all subnets , there is not much resousce to do all this as i am new to aws , do i need to update route table also it has one default route table.  @AnthonyB.